# css code doesnt work in react mainly the background

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

My react app.js looks like this

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

 function App() {
   return (
     <body>
       <div className='Home-page'>
         <button className='Start'>Start</button>
       </div>
     </body>
   );
}

export default App;
```

My App.css looks like this

```css
body {
  background: rgb(2, 0, 36);
  background: radial-gradient(
    circle,
    rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%,
    rgba(9, 9, 121, 0.8688725490196079) 52%,
    rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 100%
  );
  width: 100%;
}
.Home-page {
  text-align: center;
}

.Start {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
```

somehow the code returns a weird output

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-6ysbq8?file=src/App.jsx

[image: My output looks like this]

I hope someone will help me!!!
Thank you!

Comment: You define background twice in body css class. Maybe try doing one thing at a time and use background-color.

Comment: You don't need to write body tag in your app component. It is already there from index.html file. If you inspect the page you will see that. For background i guess you are overriding that property (probably in incorrect way) Hence you are seeing that output

Answer (score 1):

It's working fine, button is showing, background is showing!
Remove body tag from app.js and add one background at a time. Currently it's overriding the first one background.[image]

Comment: If you wanted background: rgb(2, 0, 36); then remove
  
background: radial-gradient(
    circle,
    rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%,
    rgba(9, 9, 121, 0.8688725490196079) 52%,
    rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 100%
  );